# Как сделать чтобы кнопки button не были вместе

Tags: android, android-button

Всем привет нужна помощь 
Вот у меня такая ситуация почему-то кнопки слитно друг к другу и это не удобно когда все кнопки слитно друг к другу но не могу разделить чтобы был пробел между ними

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:background="@drawable/ic_fon1">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<Button
android:id="@+id/play"
style="@style/RbButton.Inverse.Red"
android:layout_width="168dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:onClick="play"
android:text="@string/play" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/share"
style="@style/RbButton.Inverse.Green"
android:layout_width="168dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:onClick="share"
android:text="@string/share" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/setting"
style="@style/RbButton.Inverse.Orange"
android:layout_width="168dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:onClick="setting"
android:text="@string/setting" />

<Button
android:id="@+id/abuse"
style="@style/RbButton.Inverse.LightBlue"
android:layout_width="168dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:onClick="abuse"
android:text="@string/abuse" />

</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Добавьте код разметки в вопрос.

Comment: все добавил полностью код

Comment: `layout_margin`

Comment: а это не повлияет на ScrollView??

Comment: Смог решить данную проблему с помощи дополнительного LinearLayout

Answer (score 3):

Вам нужно выставить отступы (маргины) всем кнопкам.

```
android:layout_margin="10dp"
```

Также советую заменить жестко выставленную ширину (168dp) на `match_parent`. Таким образом кнопка растянется на всю ширину экрана. Маргин на 10dp поставит отступ со всех сторон, если вам нужно указать отступ с каких то определенных сторон, то используйте `layout_marginLeft`, `layout_marginTop`, `layout_marginRight`, `layout_marginBottom` для отступов слева, сверху, справа и снизу соответственно. На работу `ScrollView` это никак не повлияет

Comment: Спасибо вам большое!

Comment: @tegosyata, не за что :)

Comment: @tegosyata, если вам помог мой ответ, поставьте слева от него галочку, пометив тем самым его верным. Это облегчит поиски другим. Кстати, так у нас принято говорить "спасибо". Удачи!

Comment: вот когда ставлю match_parent то кнопка на весь экран растягивается вот и поставил 168dp

Comment: @tegosyata, если вы новичок, то можете не заморачиваться, дело в том, что на разных экранах кнопка будет разной, на планшетах маленькая, на смартфонах средняя, если экран маленький, то она вообще может не уместиться и обрезаться. Если вам нужна кнопка "почти на весь экран" то вы можете выставить `match_parent`и поставить маргины слева и справа.